# nginx / php / php-fpm | Problem with storing cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, nginx

Greetings.

I am right now in the middle of reinstalling my whole dedicated server. I went with

**-Ubuntu Server 10.10**

**-PHP 5.3.3.1**

**-php-fpm**

**-nginx**

Now, almost everything seems to work, though there remains one problem with the sessions. No matter what I do, the sessions doesn't seem to store themselves properly (and they did on the previous setup).

The base application is phpBB board. When I login, it's okay - though it appends additional SID parameter to all of the URLs.

forum/index.php?sid=f506ccd42065322f61cb56fc6df6557a

You can navigate around the forums without problem, though if you delete the SID parameter, you get logged out. I thought, that perhaps the sessions aren't stored in cookies, but in URLs, but php configuration seems fine.

The same occurs with phpMyAdmin - I also get logged out, when I delete the token parameter.

In the meantime, it seems the cookies are getting created anyway, it's like they aren't used, or are getting deleted immediately.

I am getting more and more frustrated with that, maybe someone has an idea on how to troubleshoot that? I will post any configuration files necessary.

I thought maybe it's the problem with suhosin (it wasn't installed on the previous setup), but I have no clue. The PHP config is out-of-the box atm, I only modified nginx config.

Comment: Wouldn't http://serverfault.com/ be better place to ask it?

Answer (score 2):

The various session cookie parameters are all [documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

In particular, check the "session.use_cookies", "session.use_only_cookies", and "session.trans_sid" settings. If PHP can't succesfully create a cookie, it'll fall back to the trans_sid method (which is what you're seeeing: the session ID being passed around as a query/form variable).

You can trivially check if any cookie-related headers are going out by using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) and [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) in Firefox. Both let you view the incoming/outgoing headers for requests.

Answer (score 2):

May be some usefull information can be found in `PHP-fpm error log`? Set parameters in `php.ini`

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
log_errors = On
error_log = ;
```

some file php can write in or "syslog"

Also try to look in `nginx error log`.

Does `PHP-fpm process-owner` has write permissions to `sessions dir`? See `session.save_path` on `php.ini` for `session dir`

Comment: Nothing was in logs, but after finishing all works on the server and restarting all services, and magically started to work. Guess I screwed up something at the beginning :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, be mindful of the user and group of the processes, as this will effect the default permissions that the session files are created with. If set to default, it may create as `root`, and then not be able to be read the next time the session file is accessed.

Look for `Unix user/group` of processes in your `php-fpm.conf`
and **set both user and group** to `php-fpm`

Answer (score 1):

See if your session_path is correct and has the right permissions. That fixed my problem.